# Django Form won't render

Tags: django, django-forms

My form code:

```
class PlanForm(forms.Form):
    a = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class", "add-up"}))
    b = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class", "add-up"}))

    class Media:
        javascript=('test.js', )
```

My View Code:

```
def plan_detail(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        return render(request=request,
                  template_name='pasteur/plan_detail.html',
                      dictionary={ 'message': 'This was a post request. WTF!' })
    else:
        return render(request=request,
                  template_name='pasteur/plan_detail.html',
                      dictionary={ 'form': PlanForm() })
```

Stack Trace:

> environment:
>
> Request Method: GET Request URL:
>
> Django Version: 1.4 Python Version: 2.7.2 Installed Applications:
>   ('django.contrib.auth',  'django.contrib.contenttypes', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions',  'django.contrib.sites', 
>   'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles', 
>   'django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.admindocs',  'south', 
>   'pasteur') Installed Middleware:
>   ('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')
>
> Template error: In template
>   /Users/judithjacques/dana/dev/pasteur/src/pasteur/templates/pasteur/plan_detail.html,
>   error at line 8    'set' object has no attribute 'get'    1 :
>
> Traceback: File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in get_response
>     111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) File "/Users/judithjacques/dana/dev/pasteur/src/pasteur/views.py" in
>   plan_detail
>     13.                   dictionary={ 'form': form }) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts/**init**.py"
>   in render
>     44.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py"
>   in render_to_string
>     176.         return t.render(context_instance) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in render
>     140.             return self._render(context) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in _render
>     134.         return self.nodelist.render(context) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in render
>     823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py"
>   in render_node
>     74.             return node.render(context) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py"
>   in render
>     281.                 return nodelist.render(context) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in render
>     823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py"
>   in render_node
>     74.             return node.render(context) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py"
>   in render
>     84.             output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context) File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in resolve
>     571.                 obj = self.var.resolve(context) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in resolve
>     721.             value = self._resolve_lookup(context) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in _resolve_lookup
>     772.                             current = current() File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py"
>   in as_ul
>     229.             errors_on_separate_row = False) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py"
>   in _html_output
>     171.                     label = bf.label_tag(label) or '' File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py"
>   in label_tag
>     508.         id_ = widget.attrs.get('id') or self.auto_id
>
> Exception Type: AttributeError at /pasteur/plan/create/ Exception
>   Value: 'set' object has no attribute 'get'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, `{"class", "add-up"}` is a set. You need a dictionary: `{"class": "add-up"}`.